# Meaning of 还 other than "still, also, even more"

Tags: grammar

I've got some sentences with 还. But I can't figure out the purpose of 还 in them.

1. 你还出去做什么？
   (Does it mean "still", or what?)
2. 快下雪了，我还以为今天是好天气。
   (I searched the Internet, and I found many examples that use 以为 together with 还. What does 还 mean here in this context?
3. 这些古诗我们现在恐怕还读不了。(What's the purpose of 还 here?
4. 明明这几天气温还挺高的。
5. 你要是觉得别扭，就还叫我们先生。

Comment: Please look through [previously asked questions](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E8%BF%98) first, then focus on the queries which you can't find the answer to. Based on the variety of sentences you posted here, it seems like you need help parsing the sentences more than help understanding the functions of 「還」.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question: What is the purpose of **还** (hai2) in the following sentences?

你**还**出去做什么？

快下雪了，我**还**以为今天是好天气。

这些古诗我们现在恐怕**还**读不了。

明明这几天气温**还**挺高的。

你要是觉得别扭，就**还**叫我们先生。

In the sentences, the word **还** leads us to a situation explicitly or implicitly indicated in the context of the dialogue that contradicts the current situation. Without the word **还**, the sentence could be just a plain statement. For example,

你出去做什么？- What is the purpose for you to go out?

(我已经买了饭了), 你**还**出去做什么？- (I have bought the lunch), why do you still want to go out?

Answer (score 1):

1. 你还出去做什么？
   When used in context, this usually means why you are still going out, given some new circumstances. For example, 下雨了，你还出去做什么？ (It's raining, why are you still going out?)
2. 快下雪了，我还以为今天是好天气。
   Here 还 signifies an abrupt change. I originally thought today would be a good day. But given that it's soon snowing, I abruptly change my opinion: today is a bad day.
3. 这些古诗我们现在恐怕还读不了。
   Here 还 means not yet. We are not yet ready to understand these poems.
4. 明明这几天气温还挺高的。
   This is the same usage as 2. It signifies there is an abrupt change in temperature or weather.
5. 你要是觉得别扭，就还叫我们先生。
   This 还 simply means "still". If you find it awkward, you may still call us 先生. The listener probably previous called the speaker 先生, but now should call him in a different way due to new circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

1. 你还出去做什么？ - What do you "still" (want to) go out for?
2. 快下雪了，我还以为今天是好天气。- Snow is about to come, "**yet**" I've guessed it would be a fair weather for today.
3. 这些古诗我们现在恐怕还读不了。I am afraid that we are not "**yet**" able to digest these ancient poetries.
4. 明明这几天气温还挺高的。- It is quite obvious that the temperature "still" remains quite high these days.
5. 你要是觉得别扭，就还叫我们先生。- If you feel uncomfortable, you can "still" call us "master"

Answer (score 0):

> 1. 你还出去做什么？

It means "still". It sounds to me like "(And) you are still going. For what?"

> 2. 快下雪了，我还以为今天是好天气。

It is for emphasis with no significant meaning.

"It's about to snow. Well, I thought it would be a nice weather today!" Here, well, just like 还, is just used to express your emotion.

More examples:

- 还用你说！
- 这还得了？

> 3. 这些古诗我们现在恐怕还读不了。

It means "yet."

> 4. 明明这几天气温还挺高的。

It means "fairly." When used with an adjective, 还 can act as an adverb meaning "fairly" or "reasonably". For example, 还不错哦！

> 5. 你要是觉得别扭，就还叫我们先生。

It means "still."